# .bbl is not importing all bibliography items from Bibdesk

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing my thesis in texshop, using Bibdesk as bib library. The problem I'm having is; I can't import all references into my thesis. there are 50 items and I can see only 30 of them.

I'll be glad for any help.

Comment: (1) Welcome. (2) Bibdesk is a manager programme for BibTeX files. It does not decide which items are used in your document. Bibtex only takes the items from the `.bib` file that are actually *cited* in the document. Did you cite all 50? If you just want to list all items from the `.bib` file, the add `\nocite{*}` to your document, and run latex, bibtex, latex, latex (or pdflatex ir that is what you use)

Comment: Thanks. Its working now. All the references are listed and i can cite them.

Comment: I'll make it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bibdesk is a manager programme for BibTeX files. It does not decide which items are used in your document. Bibtex only takes the items from the `.bib` file that are actually cited in the document.

Did you cite all 50?

If you just want to list all items from the `.bib` file, then add `\nocite{*}` to your document, and run latex, bibtex, latex, latex (or pdflatex if
 that is what you use)